# Send Inputs information to another html page with javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

good Evening friends, i'm trying to make a simple javaScript code that send the inputs information to another html page, and its not working for me.

i've 2 pages 
**page1.html** that contains the inputs :

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="smi.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"> </head>
<body> 

<form action="page2.html" method="post">

Tape your firstname: <input type="text" name="nom"><br>
Tape your lastname: <input type="text" name="prenom"><br>
<button type="submit">gènèrer</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the **page2.html** :

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="smi.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"> </head>
<body> 

<p id="zone" ></p>

<script src="page2.js" type="text/JavaScript"> </script>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my script :

```
var x = getUrlVars()["nom"];
var y = getUrlVars()["prenom"];
var w = getUrlVars()["Tel"];

var z = "bonjour " +x+" "+y+"votre Tel est : " +w;
document.getElementById("zone").innerText() = z;


function getUrlVars(){

var vars = {};
var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,function(m,key,value){
vars[key] = value;
});
return vars;
}
```

i hope if u can help me plz.

Comment: You need some server-side code to add the values to the page send as the response. ... or use GET instead of POST as the request method.

Comment: try using `epress` the `Node.js` framework. For this type of tasks u need some backend code,  usually it is handled by a server ( your computer con do this work too ), google it u will find many usefull things

Answer (score 2):

What @teemu said about using server side code, but you can also do something like this while learning basic HTML:

Add a page1.js with something like this:

```
function submit(){
   let fName = //get first name;
   let lName = //get last name
   location.href(`page2.html/fName=${fName}&lName=${lName}`);
}
```

Then call this function from the onsubmit button:

```
<button onClick="submit();">gènèrer</button>
```